# Ограниченный вывод в цикле

Tags: php, mysql

Добрй  день. Есть код, который выводит пагинацию на сайте. Но дело в том, что он  выводит все ссылки. Например, если у меня 1000 записей в БД, то скрипт  выведет 500 ссылок на страницы (если по 2 записи на страницу). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы в пагинации отображалось страниц 5, например.

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $CUR_PAGE=($_GET['page']);
} else {
    $CUR_PAGE=1;
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM articles");
$row=mysql_fetch_row($res);
$total_rows=$row[0];

$ITEM_PER_PAGE = 2;
$start=abs(($CUR_PAGE-1)*$ITEM_PER_PAGE);

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start,$ITEM_PER_PAGE");

require_once 'tpl/index.php';

$uri=strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"?")."?";

if (isset($_GET['page'])) unset($_GET['page']);
if (count($_GET)) {
  foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
      if ($k != "page") $uri.=urlencode($k)."=".urlencode($v)."&";
  }
}

$num_pages=ceil($total_rows/$ITEM_PER_PAGE);
for($i=1;$i<=$num_pages;$i++) $PAGES[$i]=$uri.'page='.$i;

if ($CUR_PAGE <=1) {
    echo '<span>Prev</span>';
} else {
    $j = $CUR_PAGE - 1;
    echo '<a href="?page='.$j.'">Prev</a>';
}

foreach ($PAGES as $i => $link) {
    if ($i == $CUR_PAGE) {
        echo '<b>'.$i.'</b>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$i.'</a>';
    }
}

if ($CUR_PAGE == $num_pages) {
    echo '<span>Next</span>';
} else {
    $j = $CUR_PAGE + 1;
    echo '<a href="?page='.$j.'">Next</a>';
}

if ($CUR_PAGE == $num_pages) {
    echo '<span>Last</span>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="?page='.$num_pages.'">Last</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача простая и без использования шаблонизаторов и готовых компонентов ее можно решить следующим образом:

```
$currentPage = 1; //текущая страница (CUR_PAGE)
$maxPagesCount = 5; //общее количество страниц (num_pages)
$paginatorHtmlContent = ''; //Переменная для хранения HTML кода паджинатора

$minPage = max(1, $currentPage - 5); //Минимальная страница которую нужно вывести - 5 
$maxPage = min($maxPagesCount, $currentPage + 5); //Максимальная страница от текущей + 5
for($i = $minPage;$i <= $maxPage;$i++) {
    if($maxPagesCount >= 1) {
        if($i === $currentPage) {
            $paginatorHtmlContent .= "<b>{$i}</b>";
        } else {
            $paginatorHtmlContent .= "<a href='?page={$i}'>{$i}</a>";
        }
    }
}

echo $paginatorHtmlContent;
```

Я хочу высказать некоторые рекомендации относительно вашего кода:

1. Прекратите использовать mysql* расширение, если это новый проект, переходите на более новые библиотеки вида PDO и mysqli;
2. Откажитесь от конкатенации переменных получаемых от пользователя в запросе к базе данных, т.к. с таким подходом велика вероятность SQL-инъекции;
3. Именуйте переменные в едином стиле;
4. Начните разделять данные приложения, пользовательский интерфейса и управляющую логику. Например, можете попробовать какой-нибудь фреймворк.

Comment: Небольшое замечание: в вашей реализации на краях диапазона будет показано 5+1 страниц,  а в середине 5+1+5. То есть количество страниц не всегда одинаковое.

Comment: @Firepro спасибо большое. По поводу рекомендаций: Спасибо за них. Это всего лишь черновик. Но некоторыми рекомендациями я воспользуюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Ну это же просто! Отвлекитесь на минутку от sql и html. У вас есть 500 штук и надо вывести только 5 штук.

```
$limit = 5;
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; ++$i) {
    echo $i . "\n";
}
```

Неплохо а? Теперь надо вывести 5 штук не с начала а с текущей позиции (половину слева, половину справа от текущей позиции).

```
$current = 15;
$limit = 5;
$from = $current - floor($limit / 2);
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; ++$i) {
    echo $from + $i . "\n";
}
```

Огонёк! Одно только нехорошо -- `$from` может оказаться < 1 или > 500, а этого бы не хотелось.

```
$all = 500;
$current = 15;
$limit = 5;
$from = $current - floor($limit / 2);
if ($from < 1) {
    $from = 1;
} elseif ($from > $all - $limit + 1) {
    $from = $all - $limit + 1;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; ++$i) {
    echo $from + $i . "\n";
}
```

Но кажется тут закралась ошибка. Что будет если `$all` < `$limit`? Надо это поправить.

```
$all = 4;
$current = 3;
$limit = min($all, 5);
$from = $current - floor($limit / 2);
if ($from < 1) {
    $from = 1;
} elseif ($from > $all - $limit + 1) {
    $from = $all - $limit + 1;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; ++$i) {
    echo $from + $i . "\n";
}
```

Ну и не забывайте, что вам не обязательно сразу делать `echo`, обычно удобно собрать какой-нибудь объект `Pagination`, который можно потом проитерировать в шаблоне.

Comment: Расписали все как маленькому. Спасибо большое. Да, когда  ссоберу свою систему, буду ее упрощать функциями и классами.

Comment: @PigHead это для иллюстрации поиска решения. Понимание как сделать часто приходит в процессе, а не рождается сразу целиком. От простого к более сложному.

Comment: вы правы, я все понял, спасибо, еще раз. Только вот ошибка выходит. Я поставил в $limit "3", и когда я нахожусь на посследней странице, в пагинацию добавляются неуществующие ссылки. Но ели посставить "2" в $limit, то такого бага нет.  Как я понимаю, этот баг будет только с нечетными цифрами?

Comment: @PigHead а при каких $all, $current наблюдается баг? Кстати Firepro предлагает возможно более простое для восприятия решение.

Comment: Егор, да при любых, собственно. Кроме упомянутой двойки в $limit. Любое другое значение приследует баг. Ну да, мне тоже кажется, что у него проще. Но тоже о своими минуами, которые вы заметили. Но это уже условием можно  исправить, я думаю.

Comment: @PigHead а вы точно запускаете код из последнего варианта? `$all = 50; $current = 50; $limit = min($all, 3);` -- ok, 51 - ok, 100500 -- ok, 1 -- ok... Может вы просто где-то напутали, когда внедряли этот код в своё решение?